Decoding a Swift type which is only conditionally `Codable`
I have a Swift class that may or may not be Codable. When it is Codable, I would like to be able to load it from file. Here is a bare bones example...
protocol P {
    func load()
}

final class A<T>: P {
    func load() {
        if T.self is Codable.Type {
            let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: Data())
        }
    }
}

extension A: Codable where T: Codable {}

I get an error that T is not Codable and the JSONDecoder requires it. It makes sense, because even though I do a run time check, the call to decode does not constrain T to be Codable.
I've tried a bunch of variations, like adding extensions with a where clause, but I'm yet to find the definitive answer.
Anyone know how to approach this?

import Cocoa

protocol P {
    func load(from data: Data)
}

extension P {
    func load(from data: Data) {
        // print or something
        Swift.print("P.load")
    }
}

final class A<T>: P {
}

extension A: Codable where T: Codable {
    func load(from data: Data) {
        Swift.print("A.load where T Codable")
        let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    }
}

extension A {
    func load(from data: Data) {
        Swift.print("A.load")
    }
}


let four = 4
let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(four)
A<Int>().load(from: encoded)


This worked for me in a playground. If overloading isn't working for you, then there is something like throws interacting with the compiler/runtime's choice of implementation.

My comment on another answer also applies to this solution. This only works if the concrete type of A<T> is statically known at the call site of load because in this case the compiler uses static dispatch and doesn't actually go through the protocol.

That's an interesting quirk but then making an existential by casting to some Codable first should work, no?

Seems you can actually cast a type to any Codable.Type and pass that in. Never seen it myself, but it does work.

This is what I ended up going with. My original problem was that I had the load method in the wrong extension. The compiler will only look at the immediate extension, not at what other extensions claim.

Does the class even conform to P if it’s not Codable? E.g. would something like this work?
final class A<T> {}

extension A: Codable, P where T: Codable {
    func load() {
        let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: Data())
    }
}

The downside is you can’t add another conditional conformance to P if T is not Codable…
I see the other solution was already mentioned here so removing it

Hmm, may be a good lead. Thanks! I guess I could split P out into protocols that need Codable, and some that don't. At least now it does compile.

Edited with a better solution that doesn't require a split

If having a completely separate load implementation for when T is Codable and when it isn't Codable is fine for you, you can achieve your goals by overloading the load() method and providing a more-specific implementation for T: Codable.
When calling load on an instance of A whose T is Codable, the runtime will call the more-specific load implementation that using JSONDecoder.
protocol P {
  func load()
}

final class A<T>: P {
  private var value: T

  init(value: T) {
    self.value = value
  }

  func load() {
    // Default implementation for non-Codable T
  }
}

extension A where T: Codable {
  // Specialized implementation of load using JSONDecoder for Codable T
  func load() {
    do {
      let data = ...
      let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: data)
    } catch {
      print("Failed to decode: \(error)")
    }
  }
}

extension A: Codable where T: Codable { }


I did go down this route quite a bit, but could not get Swift to trigger the right load. It seems that if the load is in the protocol, it always just takes the one from the main class, ignoring the extension.

@DrewMcCormack I've tested this example and worked fine, see this SwiftFiddle

@DavidPasztor Your solution doesn't work if the call to load is dynamically dispatched through the protocol. It works in your example because the concrete types of your two variables codableContainer and nonCodableContainer are statically known at the call site. But if that isn't the case, the call will always go to the default load implementation. Example: let codableContainer: any P = A(value: "I'm codable"); codableContainer.load() will print "Default load".

You can cast T to an any-type and then open up the existential again by passing it to a generic function. In your example, you can directly use JSONDecoder().decode.
final class A<T>: P {
    func load() {
        if let codableType = T.self as? any Codable.Type {
            let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(codableType, from: Data())
        }
    }
}

More generally speaking, you have to perform two steps in these kind of situations:
protocol Foo {
    associatedtype T
}

func doSthIfFoo(f: Any) {
    func open<F: Foo>(foo: F) {
        // do sth with foo
    }
    if let foo = f as? any Foo {
        open(foo: foo)
    }
}

Update: Here is a complete example to see how it works:
protocol P {
    func load(data: Data)
}

final class A<T>: P {
    func load(data: Data) {
        if let codableType = T.self as? any Codable.Type {
            let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(codableType, from: data)
            print(decoded)
        }
    }
}

func test<T: Codable>(value: T) {
    let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(value)
    A<T>().load(data: data)
}
 
test(value: 2) // prints 2
test(value: "test") // prints "test"


The problem here is that the JSONDecoder really needs to have a concrete type, not an existential. So I need to pass in the actual class A to that.

@DrewMcCormack By passing the existential to the generic decode-function, it is "opened up" and the concrete type is available.

OK, that's new to me. Indeed, this actually does work. When was it added to the language, because first time I've seen it I think. (Also not something anyone is likely to guess unfortunately.) Thanks!

I put this in, and it works to actually satisfy JSONDecoder. The problem then is that the returned object is typed as any Decodable & Encodable, and I can't cast it to the actual type (eg Self). Gives error "Cast from 'any Decodable & Encodable' to unrelated type 'Self' always fails"

Okay, If you want to do more, you can force-cast once you know the concrete Codable type. See https://swiftfiddle.com/hw3w7crp3nbujhnu7qixcqy5oq

@DrewMcCormack It seems it was implemented in Swift 5.7 (https://github.com/swiftlang/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0352-implicit-open-existentials.md), but I learned the trick from the pointfree-guys.
